# Functions And Relation

Tags: functions

Recently I encountered a very interesting question regarding finding domain of function and while solving it I arrived at a relation which cannot be generalized, so the question proceeds as follows:

Find the domain of the following function

$$f(x)= \frac{1}{√([x^2]-[x]^2)}$$

Where [.] represents Greatest Integer Function.

So in this I proceeded as follows:
The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{√([x²] — [x]²)}$ is defined at x if and only if $[x²] > [x]²$

Let $x = m+r$ , where m is an integer and $0\leq r<1$ Then $m = [x]$ . Hence $x² = m²+2mr+r² = [x]² + 2mr +r²$

Therefore $[x²] > [x]²$ if and only if $2mr+r²\geq1$ or $r²+2mr —1 \geq 0$ , i.e.

$2m \geq (1-r²)/r = (1/r) —r$

or $2[x] \geq (1/r) — r$ , where $r = x —[x]$ and x is not an integer.

Unfortunately this condition does not seem to be expressible in a simpler form.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly tidy it up a little.  For simplicity, I will consider only $x > 0$.

Then, you have obtained already, the number $x=m+r$ where $r \in [0,1)$ is in the domain if and only if $r^2+2mr \geqslant 1$.  Then we need,
$$
(r+m)^2 \geqslant 1+m^2
$$
which is the case if, and only if, $m > 1$ and
$$
r \geqslant \sqrt{m^2+1} - m \bumpeq \frac{1}{2m} \text{ for larger } m
$$
(taking note of our assumption $m, r$ are non-negative); expressed in terms of $x$ this becomes, for each integer $m \geqslant 1$,
$$
x \in \left[\sqrt{m^2+1},m+1\right) \bumpeq \left[ m+\frac{1}{2m}, m+1 \right)
$$
so that the domain becomes a union of disjoint of intervals,
$$
\left[\sqrt{1^2+1},2\right), \left[\sqrt{2^2+1}, 3\right), \left[\sqrt{3^2+1}, 4\right), \cdots.
$$